# Apache mod_rewrite enabled but not working?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

Running on Ubuntu Server 10.10 on a VPS. Running Apache2 with mod_rewrite enabled. phpinfo() shows mod_rewrite.

```
core mod_log_config mod_logio prefork http_core mod_so mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_file mod_authz_default mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_php5 mod_proxy mod_proxy_http mod_reqtimeout mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_status
```

Apache was freshly installed, no real changes.. just got this VPS to start experimenting on.
I enabled mod_rewrite using this command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

I created my .htaccess file and added it to my www directory containing this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^alice.html$ bob.html
```

both html files are in the same www directory as the .htaccess file, I made sure to restart the server after changes, and I have ensured there are no simply spelling or capitalization mistakes. Any suggestions would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You probably haven't allowed .htaccess files to perform mod_rewrite options.  You need to set that with [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

Comment: And unless you need to use htaccess files specifically for some reason (pretty much only shared hosting environments, which this isn't), then don't do it.  See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when).  `In general, you should only use .htaccess files when you don't have access to the main server configuration file. There is, for example, a common misconception that user authentication should always be done in .htaccess files, and, in more recent years, another misconception that mod_rewrite directives must go in .htaccess files. This is simply not the case.`

Comment: @ShaneMadden A very good point I should have included in my answer.